# How to validate XQuery source file for XSD schema

Tags: xquery, saxon

I mean without input XML file.
I'm using Saxon-EE 9.2.

Comment: What do you mean "validate XQuery file for XSD"? XML file can be validated with XSD ... Be more specific, pls.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to validate the Xquery source file then, the only route I know of is to first convert it to [XqueryX](http://www.w3.org/TR/xqueryx/) using [xq2xqx.xsl](https://bitbucket.org/victor.petrov/opentrack/src/fc3a79b98599/xq2xqx.xsl) and then use a xsd schema based on that

Answer (score 0):

An XQuery source file isn't an XML document, so can't be validated with an XML schema. If you really need to, you can use the `xq2xqx` library to convert XQuery source files into XQueryX documents:

http://monet.nag.co.uk/xq2xml/

The code there needs some tidying up, the XQuery parser linked at

http://www.w3.org/2005/qt-applets/xgrammar.zip

and the Saxon jar - the free one here should work:

http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.4HE

You should end up with a command line something like:

`java -cp "saxon9.jar;xquery.jar;trans2.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:main -o:"xq2xqx.log" -xsl:"xq2xqx.xsl" dump="no$2" xq=test.xquery`

which will generate `test.xqueryx`, and you can then validate the document against the official w3.org schema:

http://www.w3.org/2005/XQueryX/xqueryx.xsd